# Embed videos from multiple sources

Tags: php, html, youtube

I am working on an application that displays a form to the user, the user inputs a video URL to be displayed on their profile. The video could be coming from any possible source like Youtube, Vimeo, etc. Right now I'm using an `iframe` on my view.

I want the users to be able to post their videos by pasting the video URL directly from their browsers. But on most sites the url required by the iframe is different than the one displayed on the browser. For example on youtube the url displayed on the browser is `https://youtube.com/watch?v=id` but the URL used for embedding the video is`https://youtube.com/embed/id` . Is there a way to solve this the fast way or do I have to use regular expressions to rewrite each URL?

Comment: The embed url syntax is up to video provider. You need to write a regex for each provider to transform view url to embed url. Note that some providers could not even provide a way to embed.

Comment: Thanks. I waslooking for a way around the regualr expressions

Comment: You can avoid regex by extracting url querystring and rewrite url properly. Use implode() explode() properly. For youtube, take v=id parameter and rewrite url.